# PHP creates empty session in NFS shared directory

Tags: php, session, ubuntu, vagrant, nfs

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in the Vagrant VM on the OSX host machine.

Here the piece of Vagrant config to mount a folder:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/var/projects", "/projects", type: "nfs"
```

I found out that PHP cannot properly create a session on the NFS shared directory.

Here is the `test.php` script:

```
session_save_path('/projects/sessions');
session_start();

file_put_contents('/projects/sessions/file.txt', 'TEST');
```

Here is the output of the execution:

```
$ php test.php 
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/project/sessions) in Unknown on line 0
```

Here is what happens after execution:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw------- 1 502 dialout   0 Jul 21 10:13 sess_0p6bt4g3o0sofi3b7p6016jtg7
-rw-rw-r-- 1 502 dialout   4 Jul 21 10:13 file.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 502 dialout 164 Jul 21 10:12 test.php
```

As you can see, the session file is empty and is create with the strange permissions. Thus, the txt file is created without errors.

I've tried with PHP 5.4 and 5.5

Any other suggestions to try?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are mapping the nfs share to */projects* but set the session save path to */project* - is this typo just in the example?

Comment: @RobertRossmann Thanks for pointing that out - it was a typo. Sorry for that

Comment: one more kitty has been saved, thanks @VitaliyZurian

Answer (score 5):

#### Write session data

I've run into this problem as well :(

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. It has something to do with how PHP writes session data in combination with a NFS synced folder in a vagrant guest. (All other write operations function normally, it's specific to session writes.)

I eventually worked around the problem by storing sessions outside of the synced folders. In my case I simply used `/tmp`. For a vagrant guest the security risk for doing this is acceptable IMHO, because it only runs on your local machine. I wouldn't recommend this on real (production) servers though, but there you won't have this issue ;)

#### Owner / group

The owner (`502`) / group  (`dialout`) of files & directories within the synced folders is normal for a vagrant guest on a OS X host.

`502` is the *uid* of your user on the OS X host. That user has its *gid* set to `20` (`staff`), which is normal for OS X users. When mounting synced folders through NFS, the same *uid* & *gid* will show up in the vagrant guest. There the *uid* `502` isn't mapped to a user, which is why `502` will show when you do a `ls -l`. The *gid* `20` is mapped to the group `dialout`, so that's why that will show.

I'm mentioning this because you can find a lot of resources on the internet pointing to this "strange" user / group info as being the source of write problems, *but it isn't*. This is not "strange" at all (but perfectly normal for NFS synced folders on OS X hosts) and will *not* cause write problems. The fact that you can write a file with `file_put_contents()` proves that.

#### Different session handler

By default PHP will use the value `files` for the `session.save_handler` directive, which results in sessions being stored on a filesystem.

Certain extensions (like Sqlite, Memcached, Redis, etc) will register different handlers for you to use. You can enable them by setting `session.save_handler` to `sqlite`, `memcached`, `redis`, etc. Consult the proper documentation on how to configure them.

Or you can use a custom handler by setting `session.save_handler` to `user`. Then you can implement anything you like. This is a common way to store sessions in a MySQL database. These docs should get you started:

- [Custom Session Handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php)
- [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)
- [session.save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! I was doing the same workarounds. I am still curious about the root of the problem, though :)

Comment: I think the only way to find out is to look at PHP's internals and using tools like `strace`...

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before, i resolved it by changing the permissions for my project dir.

I believe that if you update the line for the drive mapping in your vagrantFile, you issue will go away. Documentation for mapping with nfs can be found at : https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html

Comment: Which permissions did you use? On the host machine or on the guest? Which line for the drive mapping should I update?

Comment: In your vagrantFile, it should be the line that starts with 'config.vm.synced_folder'.

The parameters needed are described in the following article: http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/

Comment: It says that `shared folders that have NFS enabled do not support owner/group attributes.`

Comment: odd that it wouldn't mention that here: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html

Answer (score 0):

On windows, simplest solution was to downgrade php to 5.3 which is default version in ubuntu 12.04 it worked without any problems. 
After I upgraded to 5.4 and 5.5 it stopped working.

Another workaround was to disable shared folder by removing synced_folder line in vagrant config and add mount cifs using provision file.

`mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypass //192.168.0.88/projects/new_project/public_html/ /home/new_site/public_html/`

You have to create smb share first on your host.

Comment: It is impossible to use "NFS" mounting with windows, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. However "vboxsf" mounting was producing exactly the same problem. I believe something between vbox share and php 5.4/5.5 is making the issue. Did you try 5.3? it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try that on Monday (27.10.2014) and will let you know if it worked. However, this is not an option for my current project :(

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this? I am having the exact same problem!